# optimising way of exporting a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, file-io

I want to export dataframes efficiently by avoiding the use of loops.My format is specific so I can not use any prebuilt function like pandas.to_csv...
This is what i have at the moment

```
def export(datafr,fout):
    fo=open(fout,'w')
    fo.write('#channel d '+'\" "date" - date\n')
    fo.write('#channel t '+'\" "time" - time\n')                

fo.write("#begindata\n")        
    for date in datafr.df.index:#2011-11-02 00:00:00

        record=datafr.df.ix[date]#row
        fo.write(str(date)+" ")
        for i in record:
            fo.write("%3.3f" % (i)+" ")
            fo.write("\n")
    fo.close()
```

It works, but I have to use loops what is not efficient at all with long time series. I thought about using map() or pandas.apply() but I do not get anything so far. One try:

```
site = DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 3), columns=list('bde'), index=['Utah', 'Ohio', 'Texas', 'Oregon'])
fout='c://Site.dat'
fo=open(fout,'w')
def writed(f,i,data):
    f.write(str(i)+" ")
    f.write("%3.3f" % (data)+" ")
map(writed,fo,site.index,site.values)
```

but I get this error

```
IOError: File not open for reading
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you want to write some header to an output file first, and afterwards, the data frame with formatted floats.

I believe you can still do it with pandas `to_csv` using the arguments: `mode` (set to "append" instead of default "write") and `float_format`.

So first goes the header, for example:

```
with open('filename.dat', 'w') as fo:
    fo.write('#channel d '+'\" "date" - date\n')
    # etc. etc.
```

and then just append the data frame:

```
df.to_csv('filename.dat', mode='a', float_format='%3.3f', sep=' ')
```